# How to create different build apk for different flavour in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, apk, android-build-flavors

I went through many docs but still can't find the exact solution for this

I tried all the possible command

```
flutter build apk --flavor development --release
flutter build apk --flavor staging --release

flutter build apk --flavor production --release

flutter build apk --flavor production --release
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want apk with different app id for each flavor then you have to add `applicationId` property to each flavor in `productFlavors` in app's build.gradle

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        development {
            applicationId "com.example.productFlavors"
        }
        staging {
            applicationId "com.example.staging"
        }
        production {
            applicationId "com.example.production"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i already done that in my build.gradle file 
i asked the command used to build apk for different flavours